# Jenkins ext plugin emails with customized changelog

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I installed jenkins email ext plugin. However I want to just include specific user's commits in the message and not all commits. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex option in the ${CHANGES}

From the help message:

> ${CHANGES}
>   Displays the changes since the last build.
>   **showDependencies**
>   If true, changes to projects this build depends on are shown. Defaults
>   to false
>   **showPaths** If true, the paths, modified by a commit are shown. Defaults to false
>   **format** For each commit listed, a string containing
>   %X, where %x is one of:
>   %a author
>   %d date
>   %m message
>   %p path
>   %r
>   revision
>    Not all revision systems support 
>   %d and %r. If specified
>   showPaths argument is ignored. Defaults to "[%a] %m\n"
>
> **pathFormat** A string containing %p to indicate how to print paths.
>   Defaults to "\t%p\n"
>   **regex** A regular expression.
>   **replace** A
>   replacement for all substrings of the change message that match the
>   given regular expression.